# Template for the below code:

Tags: xml, xslt

Being a new comer to XML and XSLT, i have generated a code for my requirement. However, i would like to simplify my XSLT using an XSL:template. Please advice on how to do my below code using a template.

```
<xsl:variable name="d1">
<xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:index"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$d1=16"><XDT_WW2><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW2></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=17"><XDT_WW3><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW3></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=18"><XDT_WW4><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW4></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=19"><XDT_WW5><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW5></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=20"><XDT_WW6><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW6></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=21"><XDT_WW7><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW7></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=22"><XDT_WW8><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW8></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=23"><XDT_WW9><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW9></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=24"><XDT_WW10><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW10></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=25"><XDT_WW11><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW11></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=26"><XDT_WW12><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW12></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=27"><XDT_WW13><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW13></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=28"><XDT_WW14><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW14></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=29"><XDT_WW15><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW15></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=30"><XDT_WW16><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW16></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=31"><XDT_WW17><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW17></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=32"><XDT_WW18><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW18></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=33"><XDT_WW19><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW19></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=34"><XDT_WW20><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW20></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=35"><XDT_WW21><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW21></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=36"><XDT_WW22><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW22></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=37"><XDT_WW23><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW23></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=38"><XDT_WW24><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW24></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=39"><XDT_WW25><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW25></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=40"><XDT_WW26><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW26></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=41"><XDT_WW27><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW27></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=42"><XDT_WW28><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW28></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=43"><XDT_WW29><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW29></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=44"><XDT_WW30><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW30></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=45"><XDT_WW31><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW31></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=46"><XDT_WW32><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW32></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d1=47"><XDT_WW33><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW33></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><XDT_WW1><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[15]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW1></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="d2">
<xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:index"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$d2=17"><XDT_WW3><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW3></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=18"><XDT_WW4><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW4></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=19"><XDT_WW5><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW5></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=20"><XDT_WW6><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW6></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=21"><XDT_WW7><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW7></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=22"><XDT_WW8><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW8></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=23"><XDT_WW9><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW9></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=24"><XDT_WW10><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW10></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=25"><XDT_WW11><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW11></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=26"><XDT_WW12><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW12></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=27"><XDT_WW13><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW13></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=28"><XDT_WW14><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW14></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=29"><XDT_WW15><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW15></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=30"><XDT_WW16><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW16></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=31"><XDT_WW17><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW17></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=32"><XDT_WW18><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW18></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=33"><XDT_WW19><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW19></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=34"><XDT_WW20><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW20></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=35"><XDT_WW21><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW21></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=36"><XDT_WW22><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW22></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=37"><XDT_WW23><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW23></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=38"><XDT_WW24><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW24></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=39"><XDT_WW25><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW25></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=40"><XDT_WW26><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW26></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=41"><XDT_WW27><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW27></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=42"><XDT_WW28><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW28></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=43"><XDT_WW29><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW29></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=44"><XDT_WW30><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW30></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=45"><XDT_WW31><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW31></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=46"><XDT_WW32><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW32></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$d2=47"><XDT_WW33><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW33></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><XDT_WW2><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[16]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW2></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

...

<xsl:variable name="e">
<xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:index"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$e=29"><XDT_WW15><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW15></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=30"><XDT_WW16><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW16></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=31"><XDT_WW17><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW17></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=32"><XDT_WW18><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW18></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=33"><XDT_WW19><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW19></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=34"><XDT_WW20><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW20></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=35"><XDT_WW21><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW21></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=36"><XDT_WW22><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW22></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=37"><XDT_WW23><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW23></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=38"><XDT_WW24><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW24></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=39"><XDT_WW25><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW25></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=40"><XDT_WW26><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW26></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=41"><XDT_WW27><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW27></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=42"><XDT_WW28><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW28></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=43"><XDT_WW29><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW29></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=44"><XDT_WW30><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW30></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=45"><XDT_WW31><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW31></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=46"><XDT_WW32><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW32></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$e=47"><XDT_WW33><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW33></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><XDT_WW14><xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[28]/ss:Data"/></XDT_WW14></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

And the code logic repeats many time for a total of 20+ variables. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is an extract of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook     xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">  <LastAuthor>APS_OWNER</LastAuthor>  <Created>2013-03-05T07:03:29</Created>  <Version>11.6408</Version> </DocumentProperties> <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">  <WindowHeight>8445</WindowHeight>  <WindowWidth>11115</WindowWidth>  <WindowTopX>720</WindowTopX>  <WindowTopY>375</WindowTopY>  <RefModeR1C1/>  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows> </ExcelWorkbook>
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal"> <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/> <Borders/>    <Font/> <Interior/> <NumberFormat/> <Protection/> </Style> 
<Style ss:ID="ColumnHeader">  <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Horizontal="Center"/>  <Font ss:FontName="Times New Roman" x:Family="Roman" ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>  <Interior/>  <NumberFormat/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="ColumnHeaderDate">  <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Horizontal="Center"/>  <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>  <Interior/>  <NumberFormat ss:Format="[ENG][$-409]dd\-mmm\-yy;@"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="NumberStyleBlueCell">  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right"/>  <Font/>  <Interior ss:Color="Cyan" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>  <NumberFormat ss:Format="###,###,###.00"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="TextStyleBlueCell">  <Alignment/>  <Font/>  <Interior ss:Color="Cyan" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>  <NumberFormat/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="NumberStyle">  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right"/>  <Font/>  <Interior/>  <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="NumberStyle2">  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right"/>  <Font/>  <Interior/>  <NumberFormat ss:Format="####"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="DateStyle">  <Alignment/>  <Font/>  <Interior/>  <NumberFormat ss:Format="[ENG][$-409]dd\-mmm\-yy;@"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="ColumnSum">  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right"/>  <Font ss:Color="Blue"/>  <Interior/>  
<NumberFormat ss:Format="###,###,###.00"/>   </Style>
<Style ss:ID="RowSum">  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right"/>  <Font ss:Color="Red"/>  <Interior/>  
<NumberFormat ss:Format="###,###,###.00"/>   </Style>

</Styles>    
<Worksheet ss:Name="NO_Details_Across">    
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="47" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9978" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
<Row>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NO</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="DateStyle"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2013-03-05T07:03:28</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NO</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CNG</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CNG</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SAD</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">S039</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CP4-XS</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3SK263-5-TG-E</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3SK263-E-5-ASY</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3SK263-E-5-WDQ</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NO PNX</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">468149</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="16" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">23280</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="17" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">23280</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="18" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">23280</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="19" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">46560</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="20" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">46560</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="25" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">69840</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="26" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">93120</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="27" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">69840</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="28" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">93120</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="29" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116400</Data>    </Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="30" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116400</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="31" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116400</Data>    </Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="32" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116399</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="33" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">139679</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="34" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116399</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="35" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">139680</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="37" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">93120</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="38" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116400</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="39" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">93120</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="40" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">93120</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="41" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">116400</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="44" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">69840</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Index="45" ss:StyleID="NumberStyle"><Data ss:Type="Number">419040</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and describe *the problem* -- not your attempted solution. We need: 1) The source XML document; 2) The exact wanted result from the transformation; 3) Explanation of any requirements/constraints the transformation must implement.

Comment: The source xml is quite big, it came from an Excel XML document, wherein i need to extract all data on a specific worksheet. How can i post it here? sorry, but it would be my first time to post.

Comment: Hi Dimitre. I have added an extract of the XML document that i am working with. The XSLT that i was trying to do is to read the Index value, and based on that it will choose an XML element (i.e. <XDT_WWXX></XDT_WWXX> as part of the output. Please let me know if i still need to feed additional information.

Comment: Note: The ss:Index refers to which column on excel it will appear. I am trying to load this document in an oracle table.

Comment: Note that your XML was not well-formed, as it has two Worksheet elements. I have corrected this, but you might want to double-check it is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to match **ss:Cell** elements where the **ss:Index** attribute is in a certain range. So you would start off by having a template to match these

```
<xsl:template match="ss:Cell[@ss:Index > position()][not(@ss:Index > 47)]">
```

(Note that **ss:Index** is an attribute, so you use the @ symbol to access it)

Within this you could then create the element, with its named based on the index, like so (Note the use of Attribute Value Templates here to create the element name. The curly braces indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, not output literally)

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('XDT_WW', @ss:Index - 14)}">
   <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data" />
</xsl:element>
```

Where the index of the cell is not in the range, you would have another template to match these

```
<xsl:template match="ss:Cell">
   <XDT_WW1>
      <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data" />
   </XDT_WW1>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then call the templates like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[15]" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[16]" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[17]" />
```

XSLT will always match the more specific template first (i.e. the one where the index is in the range).

In fact, to avoid some repitition of code, you could make one template a named template as well, and call it with a parameter with the new element number. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[15]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[16]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ss:Cell[17]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ss:Cell[@ss:Index > position()][not(@ss:Index > 47)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="cell">
      <xsl:with-param name="elementNumber" select="number(@ss:Index) - 14" />
     </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ss:Cell" name="cell">
     <xsl:param name="elementNumber" select="1" />
     <xsl:element name="{concat('XDT_WW', $elementNumber)}">
       <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data" />
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<XDT_WW2>23280</XDT_WW2>
<XDT_WW3>23280</XDT_WW3>
<XDT_WW4>23280</XDT_WW4>
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the feedback. I'd really like to show you my entire XSLT. I am not sure if i can insert your code into my existing code becuase i already have some <xsl:template> e.g. <xsl:template match="/">, <xsl:template match="ss:Row">

Comment: Hi Tim, maybe it's a silly question, i tried your code, but why is it asking for a value of gt and lt? what should i put in this value? can it be set to a fixed value? since i am planning to put this as part of an automated job.

Comment: Enter value for gt: 14
Enter value for lt: 48
old  90:      <xsl:template match="ss:Cell[@ss:Index &gt; position()][@ss:Index &lt; 48]">
new  90:      <xsl:template match="ss:Cell[@ss:Index 14; position()][@ss:Index 48; 48]">
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: 'ss:Cell[@ss:Index 14; position()][@ss:Index 48;
48]'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 174
ORA-06512: at line 108

Comment: `&gt;` and `&lt;` are the escaped values of `<` and `>` respectively to ensure the XML is well-formed, and should not be replaced with any numeric value. (In particular, `<` causes problems if used directly). I've made a change to use the actual symbols instead though.